# How to structure nested for loops when trying to use a function on unique combinations of several lists in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is made of several lists. I'm trying to make a nested for loop that will execute a function for each different combination of values in a few of the lists... none of those list values are needed for the function. I'm just trying to calculate a variable for each combination of the following lists in a df:

```py
list1 = [sun, sun sun, shade]
list2 = [0, 1, 0, 1]
list3 = [PA, GA, CA, FL]

new_list=[]
for p in range(len(df['list1'])):
    for q in range(len(df['list2'])):
        for t in range(len(df['list3'])):
            x = UnivariateSpline(params)
            new_list.append(x)
```

I've provided dummy code above, but the function I'm trying to run is `UnivariateSpline` from `scipy`. So I want to generate interpolated data using that function that I then append to a new list. And I want to do this for each combination of values from lists 1-2. I.e., use the function if list1=sun and list2=0, and list3=PA... if list1=sun and list2=1, and list3=PA... etc.

I know how to do it by using the `df.loc` to subset the data in all combination types and then use the function. But I'm sure there is a more streamlined way to do it than that.

Can someone help me understand how I need to have this formatted? I'm a very novice coder (as you can likely tell). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems as if you posted pseudo code since `args` and `df` aren't explained and the lists aren't directly used. Could you provide the actual code you currently have? Please also show an excerpt of the dataframe you're working on. Lastly, are you sure you want to use all possible combinations of the values instead of going through the lists in parallel?

Comment: Hi Jan, my apologies. I was trying to provide a simpler version of the code. I'm just referring to my data frame where I write ```df```.  I've added more clarifying information to the question above. And yes, you are correct! I'm actually wanting to go through the lists in parallel, not all combinations. Thanks! I'm altering the post now to elucidate these items.

Comment: Actually scratch that last part. I'm pretty sure what I'm looking for is indeed all combinations of those list values.

Comment: A more streamlined way of getting the lists' combinations is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). What I don't understand is that you don't seem to use these values for calling `UnivariateSpline`.